# PHP Warning while passing $_POST to array_key_exists()

Tags: php, arrays, post, warnings

So I am using the following style of code `if(array_key_exists('some_value', $_POST)){echo 'hi';}`

For PHP 5.2.17 I am getting a warning from this style of code. This is the warning:
`WARNING: argument 2 for array_key_exists() is not either an array or an object on line: 123`

This seems strange to me because I believe that the $_POST array should always be defined. Is that not the case? I'm not sure what would cause the $_POST array to not be considered an array. I am not resetting $_POST to anything so it should exist as an array at all times. Does anyone have any idea what is wrong. Please let me know if more information is needed and thank you for the help.

Edit: I should note that this only happens on the production server. My local environment does not have this problem.

Comment: Presumably you are testing this via a browser and not via the command line? `$_POST`, `$_GET` etc are not defined by the CLI. Obvious I know, but I have to ask...

Comment: This is indeed in a browser.

Comment: Are you using any frameworks? Notably, is it possible that anything has called `unset($_GET);` anywhere? Unsetting a superglobal in any scope propagates to all scopes. What do you get if you `var_dump($_GET);` ?

Comment: I'm running wordpress. Could wordpress be unsetting this?

Comment: I'm not aware of this behaviour in WP, however [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15538/undefined-variable-post) does seem to suggest you are not the first to run into this. What does a `var_dump()` show?

Comment: hmmmm.... I'd love to see, but that is a project. This warning only happens on live. I can test this later, and I will post my results.

Comment: Well it comes down to this: If it's `null`, something probably `unset()` it somewhere. If it's anything else, something reassigned it somewhere. Realisitically those are the two options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Superglobals`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) `$_POST` and `$_GET` are only populated if the script is `POST`ed to or `GET` from.  In your example, the reason that you'd get that error is if there was not post action to the script.  Before checking for a certain post value, you should check to make sure there was a post:

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
    //The form was posted
}
```

In that fashion.  From there, you can check for certain values using `array_key_exist`, or you can further check `isset($_POST['myKey'])`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `if(isset($_POST['some_value'])) { echo 'hi'; }` instead. Never had a problem with it.

Also check if you are not **overriding or unsetting** $_POST (or some framework you are using is doing it for you). I avoid to do so with superglobal variables since I think it is a bad practice and might give headaches like this one.

Comment: It's true that this will solve the issue - although it's still a little odd that this specific error should occur, `$_POST` should always be an array in a web server SAPI

Comment: Its true, I'm wondering why $_POST is not defined really, it just seems so strange.

Comment: not truly reliable. `$arr['x'] = null`. array_key_exists() will report TRUE, but isset() will report false.

Comment: I guess both ways should work but I always use `isset` and never had a **$_POST not defined problem**. this is strange

Comment: I've had the issue the OP has before, but it's not that $_POST isn't defined, it's that it is not an array.

Comment: @Jon what would it be then

Comment: `null` was my experience prior to Apache2.4/PHP 5.4, before that it was always defined as 'null' before.

Comment: the only reason it occurs me is that you override it. I avoid to override $_POST and similar variables since I think it is a really bad practice